# AWS loadbalancing between EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am experiencing quite a strange behaviour with AWS ELB and AWS ASG.

I gave some stress for my server and AWS ASG created 2 EC2 instances to handle the load. Both instances were running on 100% CPU utilisation so AWS ASG created two more - a 3rd and a 4th instance. The thing is that now the 3rd and 4th instances run at 0% CPU utilisation and 1st and 2nd run at ~90% CPU utilisation.

[image: 4th instance]

[image: 3rd instance]

[image: 2nd instance]

[image: 1st instance]

Why the load between instances is not shared so all of them would be loaded with ~45% CPU utilisation ? Why some instances are maxed and some stay idle?

*P.S. My AWS ASG scaling policy :*

Execute policy when:
As required to maintain Average CPU Utilization at 80

Take the action: Add or remove instances as required

Answer (score 0):

Some quick thoughts:

- Are your two new instances flagged as Healthy or Unhealthy?
- Are your two new instances within availability zones that the ALB can route to?  Your ALB might be set to span two AZs whereas your ASG might span 3.
- Are your two new instances in the correct subnets to receive traffic from the ALB?
- Are your EC2s configured with the same security groups as the two live ones?
- Is whatever service that should be running on the new instances actually running on it?